# Python - Is there a way to make typing that declared later

Tags: python, compiler-construction, interpreter, type-hinting

I was making parser stuff, and I want to make some "typing" in my code for type hinting. But, the classes of a file has been referenced and inherited each other. So, my code is now spaghetti :(

I've tried tons of numbers of cases that I can make. I tried everything in one class, and I changed the order. But, nothing has changed. Still, got errors kinda 'Unresolved reference'

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Expression(ABC):
    class Visitor(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def visit_assign(self, expr: Assign):
            pass

    @abstractmethod
    def accept(self, visitor: Visitor):
        pass

class Assign(Expression):
    def accept(self, visitor: Visitor):
        # ...
```

Assign has been declared later than Visitor class. So, it occurs "Unresolved Reference" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is to run `from __future__ import annotations`, which defers annotation parsing to runtime, allowing your code to run unmodified.

The second is to change your type annotations to *strings*, which has practically the same effect:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Expression(ABC):
    class Visitor(ABC):
        @abstractmethod
        def visit_assign(self, expr: 'Assign'):
            pass

    @abstractmethod
    def accept(self, visitor: 'Visitor'):  # not needed; for consistency only
        pass

class Assign(Expression):
    def accept(self, visitor: 'Visitor'):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for cross-references issues can be to declare what you can first and add the rest later.

So you could have something like:

```py
from abc, import ABC, abstractmethod

class Expression(ABC):
    class Visitor(ABC):
        pass

class Assign(Expression):
    def accept(self, visitor: Visitor):
        # ...

@abstractmethod
def visit_assign(self, expr: Assign):
    pass

@abstractmethod
def accept(self, visitor: Visitor):
    pass

Expression.Visitor.visit_assign = visit_assign
Expression.accept = accept
```